How to make an object spin 360 degrees without snapping
Im animating an object with 2 empties. I want the object to simulate a physics style orbital animation, but Im confused with the animation rotation properties. When it gets to 100th frame, the animation has a snapping frame. It's not the typical 360 degree rotation like a globe. Ive attached the file.


"Empty.001" starts with 0°, 0°, 0° and ends with 360°, 0°, 0° so it is back at its starting angle - that's fine for looping.
The object "Empty" however starts with 90°, 50°, 0° and ends with 90°, 360°, 0° - that's not the same orientation as it started, so of course there is a "snapping" frame. (Actually the Z rotation on frame 101 is 0.000021°, but that slight deviation from 0° should not be too noticeable.)
Either set the beginning to 90°, 0°, 0° or the end to 90°, 410°, 0°.

Thanks for help!
